# Big Query - JOIN two tables

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

We have two tables like below:

**Table A**

```
 Name | Question  | Answer
 -----+-----------+-------
 Bob  | Interest  | art_and_theatre      
 Sue  | Interest  | finances_and_investments
 Sue  | Interest  | art_and_theatre
 Joe  | Interest  | cooking_and_nutrition
 Joe  | Interest  | nutrition_and_drinks
 Joe  | Interest  | eco_life
 Joe  | Interest  | beauty
 Bob  | Interest  | nutrition_and_drinks
```

**Table B (Static)**

```
           Interest                         |   Segment
--------------------------------------------+------------------
art_and_theatre                             |   S1
cooking_and_nutrition, nutrition_and_drinks |   S2 
finances_and_investments                    |   S3
finances_and_investments                    |   S4
technology                                  |   S5
telecommunications                          |   S6
art_and_theatre                             |   S7
art_and_theatre                             |   S8
eco_life, cooking_and_nutrition, beauty     |   S9
```

**Expected table**

```
 Name | Question  | Answer
 -----+-----------+-------
 Bob  | Interest  | art_and_theatre      
 Sue  | Interest  | finances_and_investments
 Sue  | Interest  | art_and_theatre
 Joe  | Interest  | cooking_and_nutrition
 Joe  | Interest  | nutrition_and_drinks 
 Bob  | Interest  | nutrition_and_drinks
          (+)
 Bob  | Segment   | S1
 Bob  | Segment   | S7
 Bob  | Segment   | S8
 Sue  | Segment   | S3
 Sue  | Segment   | S4
 Sue  | Segment   | S1
 Sue  | Segment   | S7
 Sue  | Segment   | S8
 Joe  | Segment   | S2
 Joe  | Segment   | S9
```

As you can see, one user can have multiple interests and multiple interests can belong to one segment. Is this kind of JOIN is possible in Big Query?

**Note:** The Interest column will have one or more values. Segments need to be joined only if all the values are matched.

Comment: Why are the interests stored as a comma-delimited string? Is this something to do with Google BigQuery or just a bad data model?

Comment: That's how the raw data is stored. Can we convert it into an array type and do the join?

Comment: I understand that this is your table. But this is an anti-pattern; why is the table designed like that? In a relational database management system I would expect a separate table. You may want to change your data model. (But I don't know Google BigQuery well enough. Maybe there is something special about it to suggest such pattern?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select name, question, answer from `project.dataset.tableA`
union all
select distinct name, 'segment' as question, segment as answer
from (
  select answer, segment 
  from `project.dataset.tableB`, 
  unnest(split(interest, ', ')) answer
)
join `project.dataset.tableA`
using(answer)
-- order by question, name, answer
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: The above solution would join if any of the interests match since we are splitting the rows (OR). But the segments should be matched only if a user is having all the interests (AND).

Comment: I have added more values in the interests column.

Comment: Thanks! Can you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64643505/7463780

Comment: sure. will check shortly :o)

Comment: @g0pa1 - that question is answered too

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I'm thinking `union all` with a `join`:

```
select a.name, a.question, a.answer
from a
union all
select a.name, 'Segment', b.segment
from a join
     b
     on a.answer = b.interest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, you should be able to do it with the following SQL

```
with temp as (
   SELECT a.*, b.*
   FROM TABLEA a
   JOIN TABLEB b
    on a.answer = b.interest
)
SELECT t.Name, t.Question, t.Answer from temp
UNION ALL
SELECT t.Name, 'Segment' as Question, t.Segment as Answer from temp
```