# BigQuery - JOIN on two tables using string and array

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have two tables in BigQuery like below:

**Table A**

```
 Name | Question  | Answer
 -----+-----------+-------
 Bob  | Interest  | a
 Bob  | Interest  | b
 Sue  | Interest  | a
 Sue  | Interest  | c
 Joe  | Interest  | a
 Joe  | Interest  | b
 Joe  | Interest  | c
 Joe  | Interest  | d
```

**Table B (Static)**

```
           Interests                        |   Segment
--------------------------------------------+------------------
["a"]                                       |   S1
["a","b"]                                   |   S2 
["a", "b", "c", "d"]                        |   S3
```

**Expected table**

```
 User | Question  | Answer
 -----+-----------+-------
 Bob  | Interest  | a
 Bob  | Interest  | b
 Sue  | Interest  | a
 Sue  | Interest  | c
 Joe  | Interest  | a
 Joe  | Interest  | b
 Joe  | Interest  | c
 Joe  | Interest  | d
          (+)
 Bob  | Segment   | S1
 Bob  | Segment   | S2
 Sue  | Segment   | S1
 Joe  | Segment   | S1
 Joe  | Segment   | S2
 Joe  | Segment   | S3
```

In the above tables, the Answer field is of string type and Interests is of array type.

Pointers:

1. One user can have one or more interests.
2. One or more interests can belong to one segment.
3. A user will be assigned to a segment only when all of his interests are matched.

Any inputs/thoughts in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select name, question, answer from `project.dataset.tableA`
union all
select name, 'Segment', segment
from (
  select 
    name, 'Segment', segment,
    ( select countif(y is null)
      from b.interest x
      left join a.answers y
      on x = y
    ) = 0 qualified
  from (
    select name, array_agg(answer) answers
    from `project.dataset.tableA`
    group by name
  ) a, `project.dataset.tableB` b
)
where qualified
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm! However, I didn't quite understand the logic here. A short description would be of great help.

Comment: sure. will add comments tomorrow :o)

Comment: brief explanation: 1) most inner select - simply generates array of answers for each user; 2) then result is cross joined with segments (tableB) and `qualified` attribute is calculated (see details below in #4); 3) finally output is filtered to only those which qualified and union with tableA; 4) logic for `qualified` is to check rule #3 in your question by counting how many user's interests are above what is in segments - if it is zero - it is qualified. Hope this helps to understand better the solution in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `union all` -- where the second query unnests the interests and joins:

```
select a.name, a.question, a.answer
from a
union all
select a.name, 'segment', min(b.segment)
from a join
     (b cross join
      unnest(interests) b_interest
     )
     on a.interest = b_interest
group by name
having min(b.segment) = max(b.segment);
```

You might need a `left join`, if some interests don't have segments.

Comment: Would it also fulfill point #3? Only if all the values are in the array, it should get matched.

Comment: Getting this error `SELECT list expression references b.segment which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [11:29]` while executing the above query

Comment: Any thoughts? Looks like the segment field has to be an aggregatable value. How that can be achieved?

Comment: @Gopal . . . I fixed the answer a while ago.

Comment: Tried this.. but not getting any results. Just the initial select statement is giving the results.